# Class not found error in Lithium Framework (li3)

Tags: php, oop, lithium

I am using Lithium Framework. I am trying to call class into a controller, that class is placed inside libraries folder.... But it is showing this error

> Fatal error: Class 'app\libraries\Test' not found in /home/ali.mehdi/AvonTPH/app/controllers/SessionsagentController.php on line 34

In libraries folder I created Test.php having following code.

```
<?php
namespace app\libraries;
class Test{
  public static function getTest(){
    return "Hi";
  }
}
```

Also Inside my controller.. I used following using statements:

```
use app\libraries\Test;
```

But Why Test Class not found... Am I missing something? Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://li3.me/docs/lithium/core/Libraries::add()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Matei Mihai has commented, in your `app\config\bootstrap\libraries.php` add the line `Libraries::add('.')`, though I'd advise against this (see below).

Be aware that the best practice is to put your classes into a package and not drop them in the `libraries` folder.